# Why does .split() not appear to be working in this context? (Python)

Tags: python, split

I've got a simple block of code which is meant to iterate over a list of strings and split each item in the list into a new list, then call another function on each item:

```
list_input = take_input()
for item in list_input:
    item.split()
    system_output(item)
```

The problem is that 'item.split()' doesn't seem to be doing anything. With a print(item) statement in the penultimate line, all that is printed to the console is the contents of item, not the contents split into a new list. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, can anyone help? Thanks!

EDIT: So I've been informed that strings are immutable in Python, and in light of this replaced the 'item.split()' line with 'item = item.split()'. However, I am still running into the same error, even with item redefined as a new variable.

Comment: The first sentence in the docs for split: "**Return** a list of the words [...]"

Answer (score 1):

`split()` does not split the string  inplace, it only returns a splitted string that you have to put in an other variable.

Comment: I actually see nothing wrong with this answer, why the downvote without an explanation?

Comment: @jadsq Thanks, I tried using item = item.split() but even as a new variable, it is still not separating the words into different elements.